# What is root cause of the issue that is a program minimized to Taskbar will not reopen?

Tags: c#

I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64bit and all has been good for a long time. But, recently, when I minimize my app (which is coded myself) to the Taskbar, I am then not able to restore it to an open window. If I shut down the app process and then re-start it, my app re-starts normally and runs in an open window.

I wonder that what the root cause of the issue is. The  issue comes from Window OS or my app?
Please give me your opinion about that!

Comment: Do you have code to show?

Comment: @puretppc my app is simple hello program